# MySQL Rowsum over Columns With Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| userid | z0 | z1 | z2 | z3 | z4 | z5 |
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 4711   |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
| 4712   |  1 |  1 |  8 |  0 |  5 |  0 |
| 4713   |  3 |  5 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
| 4714   |  0 |  4 |  2 |  0 | 11 |  0 |
+--------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

This table records the number of events that happened in a certain timeframe. That is, the number of page views to a website from a certain user id at a given timeframe (0-4, 4-8, 8-12, 12-16, 16-20, 20-24 o'clock).

I would like to calculate the following using SQL:
How many timeframes are there (per user), that have at least one visit?
How many timeframes are there (per user), that have at least k visits (k=5,10)?

The desired result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| userid | visit1 | visit5 | visit10 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| 4711   |     2  |      0 |       0 |
| 4712   |     4  |      2 |       0 |
| 4713   |     3  |      1 |       0 |
| 4714   |     3  |      1 |       1 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

What I have so far:
For the question: "How many timeframes are there (per user), that have at least one visit?" I have tried something like this, but that did not work:

```
SELECT 
SUM(
  CASE WHEN z0>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  CASE WHEN z1>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  CASE WHEN z2>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  CASE WHEN z3>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  CASE WHEN z4>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
  CASE WHEN z5>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
) AS visit1
FROM timetable ;
```

Comment: I'd start by revising the schema design. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: Please, state if the columns are static (always 1, 5, 10)

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your schema, a valid query might look something like this:

```
SELECT userid
     , SUM(k>=1)  visit1
     , SUM(k>=5)  visit5
     , SUM(k>=10) visit10 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

As strawberry mentioned, it is better to revise your schema design. However, if you only want to get the result you desired, you can try this (not the best solution):

```
SELECT  userid,
    z0 + z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 + z5 as visit1,
    z0_5 + z1_5 + z2_5 + z3_5 + z4_5 + z5_5 as visit5,
    z0_10 + z1_10 + z2_10 + z3_10 + z4_10 + z5_10 as visit10

FROM (
   SELECT 
   userid,

   CASE WHEN z0>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z0,
   CASE WHEN z1>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z1,
   CASE WHEN z2>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z2,
   CASE WHEN z3>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z3,
   CASE WHEN z4>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z4,
   CASE WHEN z5>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z5,

   CASE WHEN z0>4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z0_5,
   CASE WHEN z1>4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z1_5,
   CASE WHEN z2>4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z2_5,
   CASE WHEN z3>4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z3_5,
   CASE WHEN z4>4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z4_5,
   CASE WHEN z5>4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z5_5,

   CASE WHEN z0>9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z0_10,
   CASE WHEN z1>9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z1_10,
   CASE WHEN z2>9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z2_10,
   CASE WHEN z3>9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z3_10,
   CASE WHEN z4>9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z4_10,
   CASE WHEN z5>9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END z5_10

   FROM timetable 
   GROUP BY userid
) as test
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/623f10/1)

Answer (score 0):

based on your existing structure, which IF you can adjust to a better format would make things much easier... but not withstanding, try

```
select
      userid,
        case when z0 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z1 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z2 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z3 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z4 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z5 >= 1 then 1 else 0 end as Visit1Group,
        case when z0 >= 5 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z1 >= 5 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z2 >= 5 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z3 >= 5 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z4 >= 5 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z5 >= 5 then 1 else 0 end as Visit5Group,
        case when z0 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z1 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z2 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z3 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z4 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
      + case when z5 >= 10 then 1 else 0 end as Visit10Group
   FROM 
      timetable ;
```